# Interfacing RDM6300 RFID Module with PIC Microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, rfid, mplab

I interfaced RDM6300 RFID module with 16F877A PIC. But It seems does not work although I connected it properly. I followed this [Tutorial](https://electrosome.com/em-18-rfid-module-pic/) correctly. So need to know whether this RDM6300 support for this task and if yes, Are there any changes I need to do other than the VCC, GND and TX. (I put those pins according to the RDM6300 datasheet). Can anyone give me a better solution or the tutorial link.

I'm using 
MPLAB XC8 Code.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of low level :)

First try to minimize the number of unknowns. In your case it looks like it's your first time with RDM6300 and the PIC chip, so try connecting either to your PC (with appropriate serial<->TTL level shifter) to confirm serial interfaces on both work properly and with correct baud rate.

Then connect them together.

When something doesn't work you'll need to investigate a bit. A voltmeter is a must, so you can at least check the power supplies are correct. A logical analyser or oscilloscope would be great, as you could check what (if any) signal is being transferred on data lines.

Hopefully this provides some starting pointers.

When you encounter an issue you can't solve, simplify it into the smallest possible issue with the error you see, and then ask a question - you'll have much greater chance of a useful answer. Often just doing this will make you realise what the problem is before even asking for help.